# Upload files to SFTP server and delete or archive the source files afterwards

Tags: ftp, synchronization, backup, sftp, winscp

I can't figure out a way to automatically sync files with an SFTP server that will do the following.

1. Syncs files from local PC to the SFTP
2. After upload deletes the file on the local PC and keeps SFTP file or
3. After upload moves the file that has been uploaded to another file for review.

I've tried using Ftpbox but it doesn't have the options.
WinSCP but couldn't find a script that would work.
Remote-Sync but didn't have the options.

Comment: What language are you implementing this in?

Comment: Well it's a Windows PC. I haven't thought about programming it other than Winscp scripts. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What does it mean *"sync from local pc to sftp" ... "after upload deletes the file on the local pc"*. It looks like you actually want to *"move the local files to SFTP server"*, right?

Comment: Yes the files should upload from the local pc to the SFTP server then the uploaded file on the local pc should either auto delete or auto move once uploaded to the SFTP Server.

Answer (score 0):

If just want to move local files to a remote folder, use the WinSCP [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) with the `-delete` switch.

A full Windows batch file would be like:

```
winscp.net /log=upload.log /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...=""" ^
    "put -delete C:\local\path\* /remote/path/" ^
    "exit"
```

Have WinSCP [generate the `open` command or even a complete batch file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl) for you.

---

If you want to move/archive the local files to another local folder after the upload, it is more complicated.

See the official WinSCP example [Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload).